# Error: YAML parse error - error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: control characters are not allowed

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using PostgreSQL helm chart and facing an issue while adding an init.sql script in the `/charts/postgresql/files/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` and running `helm install` 
and I am getting the following issue -

```
Error: YAML parse error on iriusrisk/charts/postgresql/templates/._metrics-configmap.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: control characters are not allowed
```

I believe it has more to do with some issue introduced by Mac I am currently using MacOS Mojave Version - 10.14.6

I have uploaded the files here https://github.com/prav10194/helm-chart and the https://github.com/prav10194/helm-chart/blob/master/charts/postgresql-8.6.16.tgz is the one with the sql script and https://github.com/prav10194/helm-chart/blob/master/charts/postgresql-8.6.12.tgz is without the sql script.

Running it on minikube version: v1.6.2

Helm version:

```
version.BuildInfo{Version:"`v3.0.2`", GitCommit:"19e47ee3283ae98139d98460de796c1be1e3975f", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.5"}
```

Comment: note the filename `._metrics-configmap.yaml` - its probably some compression or move corruption that created this binary

Answer (score 1):

Your error doesn't seem to have much to do with Mac. While it's not informative, it looks like the problem is that Helm can't find the chart version 8.1.16: it doesn't exist in Bitnami repo and the version is not updated in your local `Chart.yaml`. Here's what I did to replicate it:

1. Cloned the repo.
2. Changed the version in `requirements.yaml` from `*` to `8.6.16`.
3. Ran `helm install . --generate-name`

Got this error:

```
Error: YAML parse error on iriusrisk/charts/postgresql/templates/.__helpers.tpl: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: control characters are not allowed
```

If your error has the same origins, here's what you can do to fix it (provided you start from a clean clone of your repo):

1. Delete the archive for `8.6.12`.
2. Unpack the archive for `8.6.16` and delete it as well. You will now have `charts/postgresql` directory.
3. Go to `charts/postgresql/Chart.yaml` and update the version there to `8.6.16`.
4. Go to `requirements.yaml` and change the version to `8.6.16`. You can also remove/comment the `repository` line as you're using the local chart.
5. Delete `requirements.lock`.
6. Run `helm install . <your name or --generate-name>`

You should now have `8.6.16` installed in your minikube cluster.

Tested using minikube 1.9.0 on macOS 10.15.4 (19E266) with Helm 3.1.2.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will try it out.